# How open same page on diffrent tab on browser with different value

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

I'm on develop a website using JSF, I got a problem on page that contain model Id, when I tried to open a same page twice on different tab browser, the value is same. How to set Id on every page to be able to show the right values ? or maybe What the name of the method ?. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Different browser tabs share allways a session. If you want to have local tab data, you need to identify separate browser tabs.

I did it this way:

1. window.name is the only browser object with different memory per tab I found
2. use window.name to hold the tab-id
3. the browser is responsible for a generation of a uniq tab id if window.name is empty
4. the generated tab-id is written in window.name
5. the tab-id has to be in every url of the application
6. a view scoped bean fetches (early) this tab-id and provides a per tab memory, hold by a session bean per tab-id
7. use the tab memory instead of session memory